# ms sql error:column name or number of supplied values does not match

Tags: sql, sql-server, cursor, table

Возникает вот такая вот ошибка.

Связь между таблицами:

tab1.id ключ

tab1.id 1 ко многим tab2.tab1id

tab1.id 1 ко многим tab3.tab1id

Если же я это делаю не внутри CURSOR-а (явно подставляю @id), то всё ОК.

```
DECLARE @id  INT

DECLARE cur CURSOR FOR
SELECT tab1.id
FROM tab1
WHERE tab1.id is not NULL
ORDER BY tab1.id

OPEN cur
FETCH NEXT FROM cur INTO @id  
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN

DECLARE @temp table(tabId1 int, tabId2 int)

INSERT INTO @temp
SELECT 
       tab1.id, tab2.id
FROM 
    tab1, tab3, tab2    
WHERE 
    tab1.id = @id  
AND tab1.id = tab2.tab1id  
AND tab1.id = tab3.tab1id  
GROUP BY tab1.id, tab2.id
HAVING DATEDIFF(day,MIN(tab3.date),MAX(tab3.date)) < MAX(tab3.days)

...

FETCH NEXT FROM cur INTO @id 
END

CLOSE cur

DEALLOCATE cur
```

Comment: Вы объявляете табличную переменную на каждом шаге цикла.

Comment: я вынес @temp за cursor, но ошибка не исчезла

Comment: Здесь, похоже, вы всегда будете получать отрицательное значение:

DATEDIFF(day,MAX(tab3.date),MIN(tab3.date))

Comment: Ок, это я исправил, но ошибка осталась такая же, если я явно задаю @id, то всё ок, если в cursor-е, то ошибка "Column name or number of supplied values does not match table definition."

Comment: Сделайте тестовый пример. Уберите лишнее - кто его знает, что у вас скрывается за "...".

Comment: Ошибка вылезает на FROM и WHERE, по поводу ... - там всё ок

Comment: Ну, тогда проверяйте имена столбцов в этих таблицах.